# map function with table is not working in React

Tags: reactjs

Here's the code that I want to render table data with map function in the child component:

```
    const serviceFeeTableData = this.props.serviceFeeTableData;
    const serviceFeeDataTable = serviceFeeTableData.map(serviceFeeDataRow => {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{`${serviceFeeDataRow.periodFrom} - ${serviceFeeDataRow.periodTo}`}</td>
                <td>{serviceFeeDataRow.serviceFeeType}</td>
                <td>{serviceFeeDataRow.serviceFee}</td>
                <td>{serviceFeeDataRow.refundableStatus}</td>
                <td>
                    <Button variant="primary" size="sm">Edit</Button>
                    <Button variant="danger" size="sm">Remove</Button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    })
```

[image]

Comment: `serviceFeeTableData` is an `object`, `map` is used on an `array`.

Comment: You can use Object methods like `Object.keys`, `Object.values` or `Object.entries` to transform into an array then map over the properties

Comment: For sure you are passing the wrong property to the child component. Can you show us the parent component code?

Comment: Also remember to add the `key` property to your `tr` as explained here https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/EshanRajapakshe/Lvh6q84t/

Comment: @Emanuele Please find the link to my parent component code

Answer (score 1):

As you shown here https://jsfiddle.net/EshanRajapakshe/Lvh6q84t/ the problem is that the state of the parent component only contains one element (and also the response seems to contain only one element)

```
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.getServiceFeeData && nextProps.getServiceFeeData.length > 0) {
            this.setState({
                periodFrom: nextProps.getServiceFeeData.periodFrom,
                periodTo: nextProps.getServiceFeeData.periodTo,
                serviceFeeType: nextProps.getServiceFeeData.serviceFeeType,
                serviceFee: nextProps.getServiceFeeData.serviceFee,
                refundableStatus: nextProps.getServiceFeeData.refundableStatus
            })
        }
    }
```

You should check the URL you are calling to get a list of data (if you are trying to get the list).

Note also that `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated as described here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 1):

const object = {0: {name: 'Stepan'}, 1: {name: 'Oleg'}} // You can not map Object keys
const array = Object.keys(object); // create array from object

array.map(key => object[key]);